# How do I install libGLU1 in cygwin?

Tags: cygwin

I am trying to install VirtialGL in Cygwin.

I ran into the following

```
Problem 1/1
nothing provides libGLU1 needed by VirtualGL-2.6.3-20191024
Solution 1/1 (default)
  - do not ask to install VirtualGL-2.6.3-20191024
```

I am not able to find libGLU1 even if I try to install libGLU1 prior to installing VirtualGL.

Any suggestions on how to install libGLU1  in cygwin will be of great help!

Comment: Have you followed the instructions at [VirtualGL | Documentation / Installing VirtualGL on Cygwin](https://virtualgl.org/Documentation/Cygwin)?

Comment: If they don't work you need to contact the VirtualGL maintainers.

Answer (score 0):

Install libGLU1 from a Cygwin mirror before installing VirtualGL
from their own mirror.

https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/libGLU1.html

Answer (score 0):

Please start cygwin's installer, Choose "Install from Internet" to Donwload Source, Select and install "libglu1", "libXtst6" and "libturbojpeg0" package.
And start vglcygsetup, you would be proceeded it.